# How to update column with system date using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sysdate

I tried `getdate()` function, made a string and converted to date and did an update query but it won't work (I'm new to php)

```
$date = getdate();
$mydate = $date['mon']."/".$date['mday']."/".$date['year'];
$time = strtotime('$mydate');
$newformat = date('Y-d-m');
$sql = "UPDATE product SET p_date =".$newformat. "WHERE p_id = 2";
```

It won't update, may be the query is wrong, I just want to update table with the system date.

Comment: can you post how you tried?

Comment: try this bro '$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES ('$date')");'

Comment: Use parameters for several reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said in php this is the format

```
Correct format for a MySQL DATETIME column is
<?php $mysqltime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $phptime); ?>
```

Try this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (datePosted) VALUES ('$date')");
```

Take a look at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#85692).Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the function should be

> date() not getdate()

```
<?php
 $date = date('Y-m-d');
 $time = date("H:i:s", time());
 echo "$date or $time";
?>
```

Working Version

```
<?php
 $datetime = date('Y-m-d') . " - " . date(" H:i:s", time());
 $sql = "UPDATE product SET p_date = $datetime WHERE p_id = 2"";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // set your timezone
 $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "UPDATE product SET p_date ='$date' WHERE p_id = 2";
```